# Prevent pen or pencil moving from vertical to horizontal in my trouser pocket

Tags: clothing

I like to keep my pen handy in my trouser pocket and, although I place it vertically in my pocket, in no time at all, it has moved into the horizontal position, not only taking up much more space, but it's very uncomfortable too.

Has anyone got any suggestions as to how I can prevent these pesky pens from wriggling out of position?

Comment: What kind pen are talking about? Do you happen to have a photo for us?

Answer (score 3):

Slip a pocket clip onto your pen and clip it to the side of your pocket. If you don't want a clip on your pen, put the clip on a tube, clip the tube to your pocket, and keep the pen in the tube. They're inexpensive, and can be slightly embiggened or smallified to fit different diameters.
[image: metal pen/pencil pocket clip]
Good luck.

Comment: +1 for the use of 'embiggened'.  There are also spring clip versions of this https://www.motorsport-tools.com/stainless-steel-pen-pencil-spring-clip-single-pocket-holder-pilot-nurse-doctor.html

Answer (score 0):

You could try taking two ribbons of paper, the length of the ribbons being the width of your pocket and connecting them with a scotch tape at the ends but not in the middle, leaving a hole for the pen:

[image: Two paper ribbons adhered face to face but with a central opening]